# How to include INSERT within the CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to `INSERT` records into table when the `CASE WHEN` statement fulfilled. Otherwise `INSERT` some other records into table.

```
SELECT CASE
    SELECT CASE WHEN @AmountPaid > (SELECT InvAmount from Invoice where InvNo = @InvNo) THEN
    INSERT INTO PaymentMemo (fld1,fld2,fld3) values(valu1,valu2,valu3)
    WHEN @AmountPaid = (SELECT InvAmount from Invoice where InvNo = @InvNo) THEN
    INSERT INTO PaymentMemo (fld1,fld2,fld3) values(valu4,valu5,valu6)
END
```

How to use `INSERT` statement with two conditions.

Comment: A normal [IF... ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can't solve your issue?

Comment: I think more that IF ELSE, SELECT CASE more effective. Thats why I try SELECT CASE

Comment: Your two conditions are the same..? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve - I don't fully understand your goal here..

Comment: Dear Qirel, No 2 conditions are not same. But INSERT into same table with different values.

Comment: Ahh, sorry - too early for me, didn't see `>` vs `=`, just saw the query was the same..

Comment: From where do you get  `valuX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that :

```
insert into PaymentMemo (fld1,fld2,fld3)
SELECT CASE WHEN @AmountPaid > InvAmount then valu1 WHEN @AmountPaid = InvAmount then valu4 end,  
       CASE WHEN @AmountPaid > InvAmount then valu2 WHEN @AmountPaid = InvAmount then valu5 end,
       CASE WHEN @AmountPaid > InvAmount then valu3 WHEN @AmountPaid = InvAmount then valu6 end,
from Invoice where InvNo = @InvNo
```

Or use dynamic statement like :

```
declare @InsertStmnt nvarchar(max)

SELECT @InsertStmnt=  CASE
    SELECT CASE WHEN @AmountPaid > (SELECT InvAmount from Invoice where InvNo = @InvNo) THEN
    'INSERT INTO PaymentMemo (fld1,fld2,fld3) values(valu1,valu2,valu3)'
    WHEN @AmountPaid = (SELECT InvAmount from Invoice where InvNo = @InvNo) THEN
    'INSERT INTO PaymentMemo (fld1,fld2,fld3) values(valu4,valu5,valu6)'
END

exec (@InsertStmnt)
```

you can pass `valu1,valu2,valu3` or `valu4,valu5,valu6` dynamically

Comment: @Mark . . . This code is not syntactically correct and could be inserting lots of `NULL` values, so it is surprising that you accepted it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes your right, i'll edit it, but i guess he used the first one